# Add multiple axis on lineWithFocusChart

Tags: nvd3.js

Is there any way to add multiple axis on lineWithFocusChart .

I want to add my y2axis on right side of the graph.

[image]

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Since **lineWithFocusChart** does not support Dual Y Axes feature, I am now implementing the chart sample given by Stephen Bannasch in the blog -->  [Stephen Bannasch’s Block ](http://bl.ocks.org/stepheneb/1182434)   
If I come across any other alternative for this, will surely comment here.

Comment: thanks for response here but instead of nvd3 u can use only d3 lib. D3 support many features like multi axis , multi line , focus , zoom able etc

Answer (score 0):

There is a default option in the NVD3 library to draw multiple axis chart. Just look into the example of multichart at [the documentation website of the library](https://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/multiChart.html). And [a sample html file](https://github.com/nvd3-community/nvd3/blob/gh-pages/examples/multiChart.html) is provided on the github repo of nvd3

You can use Barchart, Areachart and line chart for multiple axis.

Just draw the graph with

```
var chart = nv.models.multiChart()
```

And change the yAxis variable to draw the graph on left yaxis or right yaxis like this.

```
  testdata[0].type = "area";
    testdata[0].yAxis = 1;
    testdata[1].type = "area";
    testdata[1].yAxis = 1;
    testdata[2].type = "line";
    testdata[2].yAxis = 1;
    testdata[3].type = "line";
    testdata[3].yAxis = 2;
    testdata[4].type = "bar";
    testdata[4].yAxis = 2;
    testdata[5].type = "bar";
    testdata[5].yAxis = 2;
    testdata[6].type = "bar";
    testdata[6].yAxis = 2;
```